# Device no longer listed after clicking ENABLE LOCK & ERASE?

Tags: android-device-manager

I clicked ENABLE LOCK AND ERASE since someone stole my device. After a day, The device is no longer listed in the android device manager. Can anyone tell, what happened?

Answer (score 1):

```
I clicked ENABLE LOCK AND ERASE
```

And that's the issue. You erased the device, along with its binding to your Google account. That's why it does not appear. *FYI, Erase should be a last resort. Lock it, grab the IMEI, report to law enforcement. That's what you do.*

Comment: But there was no spearate option for lock and erase.

Comment: @KazeTdr Huh. Well, that's a Google issue. The bit about removing the account bind is still right AFAIK.